# Scala and AKKA for a simulation

Tags: multithreading, scala, parallel-processing, akka, simulation

Should I learn scala and AKKA for a simulation project. Are these technologies a good fit / worth the investment? The task is to perform https://www.dropbox.com/s/3lby24y26wp60to/assignment.pdf?dl=0 an event-based simulation to simulate an IOT edge data center and implement some scheduling algorithms.

If yes, which libraries would you suggest? https://github.com/scalation/scalation does not seem to be a parallel library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an opinion-based question. Should not be asked here.

Anyways, I'm going to try to give you some pointers. Akka is a generic framework: you can build anything from it, but nothing in particular is an immediate fit (ok, some things fit better than others, but still).

In your case, while Akka is a valid fit (actors = agents), I'd look more into specialized softwares for ABM (Agent based modeling), you can find a massive list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_agent-based_modeling_software) .

In particular, I recommend [Netlogo](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/): it's a bit counterintuitive in terms of syntax if you have never used something akin to Lisp or other immutable variables languages ("let" etc.), but once you get the hang of it it's very powerful for the effort required.

And, if you come from a CS background, it should be super easy for you (it's normally used by non-CS people in various fields, and it's designed to be easy).